# STM32F105, arm-none-eabi-gcc, Contiki: Storing float in struct and printing float in C fails

Tags: struct, malloc, stm32, cortex-m, contiki

I have two `typedef struct` as shown below:

```
typedef struct{
    UInt32  length;
    void*   data;
    UInt16  value;
} my_type;

typedef struct{
    UInt8   type;
    UInt32  length;
    void*   value;
} tlv_t;
```

What I trying next is to allocate memory for an `my_type` struct, a `tlv_t` struct that is pointed to from the created `my_type` object and for a float number, which is pointed to from the `tlv_t` object.
If I'm executing the code without the last line of the code below it is working well. I can store the value and I can access it.
But as soon as I try to access it a second time the uploaded code isn't running at all anymore on the STM32F105 Contiki-based board. The odd part is that this is only the case when using floating point numbers. No problems at all with other datatypes like `int`. Unfortunately, I really need to use `float`... What am I doing wrong?
Another problem is that `printf` doesn't support some flags like `%f` or `%ul`. Does anybody know how to add support for it on Contiki?

```
my_type* t = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
t->data = malloc(sizeof(tlv_t));
tlv_t* tv = t->data;

tv->type = 10;
tv->length = sizeof(float);
tv->value = malloc(sizeof(float));    
*(float*) tv->value = 212.32;


printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); 
printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); // without this line it is working
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add these typedefs:

```
typedef unsigned char UInt8;
typedef unsigned short UInt16;
typedef unsigned long UInt32;
```

**EDIT2:**
Here is the complete code:

```
#include <contiki.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cfs/cfs.h>
#include <cfs/cfs-coffee.h>
#include "arg.h"

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PROCESS(main_process, "Contiki CLV build015_1");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&main_process);
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

PROCESS_THREAD(main_process, ev, data)
{
    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    my_type* t = malloc(sizeof(my_type));
    t->data = malloc(sizeof(tlv_t));
    tlv_t* tv = t->data;

    tv->type = 10;
    tv->length = sizeof(float);
    tv->value = malloc(sizeof(float));    
    *(float*) tv->value = 212.32;


    printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); 
    printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); // without this line it is working

    while (1) {
      PROCESS_YIELD();
    }

    PROCESS_END();
}
```

**EDIT3:**

I'm using the latest arm-none-eabi-gcc (version 4_8-2013q4-20131204). Are there any known issues when dealing with structs, floats or memory management?

Comment: In 3d line `tlv_t* tv = t->data;` `t->data is a void pntr` and `tv points to tlv_t`. You should do `tlv_t *tv = (tlv_t *)t->data;`.

Comment: You have probably corrupted stack somewhere else in your code.

Comment: This code works fine if you replace `Uint8` by `uint8_t` (same for `Uint32`) from stdint.h and compile with gcc on ubuntu. The trouble seems to come from elsewhere. Could you print `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(int)` ?

Comment: I just added the typedefs that were missing. @francis `sizeof(float)` is 4 and `sizeof(int)` is 4, too. @Marian I spent two days finding the problem. And up there is everything that's left to reproduce the error. @valter The problem also occurs with type casting.

Comment: Try a very simple code to see if it works.`float f = 212.32;   printf("%d \n", (int)f);      printf("%d \n", (int)f);`.

Comment: @valter yes, it's working, printing 212 two times.

Comment: Try `float f = 212.32; memmove(tv->value, &f, 4);` and remove `*(float*) tv->value = 212.32;`. If that doesnt work post the complete code.

Comment: @valter Thank you. Wow, I thought it would work. It worked for this example but as soon as I for example print the address of t it stops working again. I added the complete code on top.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
PROCESS_THREAD(main_process, ev, data)
{
    static my_type *t;
    static tlv_t *tv;
    static float f = 212.32;

    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    t = (my_type *)malloc(sizeof(my_type));
    t->data = malloc(sizeof(tlv_t));
    tv = (tlv_t *)t->data;

    tv->type = 10;
    tv->length = sizeof(float);
    tv->value = malloc(sizeof(float));    
    //*(float *) tv->value = 212.32;

    memmove(tv->value, &f, 4);


    printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); 
    printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); // without this line it is working
    printf("t address: %x \n", (unsigned int)t);

    while (1) {
        PROCESS_YIELD();
    }

    PROCESS_END();
}
```

Comment: @raspi Just put everything outside the `PROCESS_BEGIN();` except the printf's

Comment: You mean to put it above `PROCESS_BEGIN();`? Still no difference.

Comment: @raspi how do you print the address of t?

Comment: `printf("address of t: %p\n", t);` but the problem still occurs without it when using your code above.

Comment: @raspi Use `memb_alloc and memb_free` instead of `malloc and free`

Comment: Okay, I changed the code to use the memb.h functions with `MEMB`, `memb_init` and `memb_alloc`. The results are identical to those before. I can read the value once but not more..

Comment: @raspi Try `*(float *) tv->value = 212.32; float *f = (float *)tv->value; and printf("%i \n", (int)(*f));`

Comment: That makes no difference. That's just a workaround to access the value several times (like `memmove` before) but it's not solving my problem. As soon as I for example access `t` again the code fails to run completely.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46076/discussion-between-raspi-and-valter)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you fix your code, so you get no compiler warnings anymore (don't turn them off). Add casts as needed. 
After I did those fixes your code worked for me, so the code is ugly but ok.

```
#define UInt32 unsigned int
#define UInt16 unsigned short
#define UInt8 unsigned char

typedef struct{
    UInt32  length;
    void*   data;
    UInt16  value;
} my_type;

typedef struct{
    UInt8   type;
    UInt32  length;
    void*   value;
} tlv_t;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    my_type* t = (my_type*)malloc(sizeof(my_type));
    t->data = malloc(sizeof(tlv_t));
    tlv_t* tv = (tlv_t*)t->data;

    tv->type = 10;
    tv->length = sizeof(float);
    tv->value = malloc(sizeof(float));    
    *(float*) tv->value = (float)212.32;


    printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); 
    printf("tv->value: %i\n", (int) *(float*) tv->value); // without this line it
    getchar();
}
```

gives 
    tv->value: 212
    tv->value: 212

Comment: Just added some casts for the pointers and the the float-cast for the assignement of 212.32.

Comment: That's not solving my problem. Even without casts I get no compiler warnings (they are turned on).